# Changing html content of a div before and after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to change the button "ADD" (in a div) to some text/img as soon as it is clicked. And after the ajax request is processed, in the success block ,  I want the div to get the button back. 
I see the ajax request is itself not getting processed. Can someone explain whats my mistake.

I just removed the jsfiddle link and pasting the script here to avoid confusion about the dependencies.

JS script

`var ajax_load = "Please wait...";
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $("#add_button").click(function(event){
             var st = $("#add_div").html();
             $("#add_div").html(ajax_load);
             $("#sform").validate({ errorClass: "error",
                     submitHandler: function (form) {
                     alert('inside submit');
                     $.ajax({
                              type: "GET",
                              url: 'form.cgi',
                              data: $("#sform").serialize(),
                              success: function (msg) {
                                              alert('msg');
                                              $("#add_div").html(st); 
                                              $("#sform")[0].reset();
                              }
                       });
                   }
           });
        });
     });`

And the html piece is

`<form id=sform>LABEL
        <input id=field1 type=text>
        <div id="add_div">
            <input type="button" value="ADD" id="add_button">
        </div>
    </form>`

I have **jquery.validate.min.js** script included.

Comment: You have dependencies in your fiddle that don't work so we can't test it. But step one is you don't need to call `load` on `$("#addsitecode_submit")`. You already did an Ajax call, and load will try to do another (and fail because you have no params). Just do `$("#addsitecode_submit").html(...)`.

Comment: Why use a button click instead of $('form').submit(function(){}); This would allow a user to use the enter key as well. Change text in onclick, change it back on ajax.always()

Comment: No reference to `validate.js` ?

Comment: @gwcoffey - I removed the .load but still it wont work.
 The code inside submitHandler() is working well if i remove the lines which are manipulating the button ADD to and fro text.

Comment: @shaunakde - I read validate() is already jquery's function (http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Comment: Thanks @shaunakde. I have it inlcuded in my project- jquery.validate.min.js. Leaving the jsfiddle., I need help to make it work in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsfiddle needs jQuery library, which was missing. If you fulfill jQuery dependencies, you'll have no problems making the AJAX request.

Coming to your second question, you can use the jquery.ajax's beforeSend property to do whatever that you desire. Read up on the documentation.

Comment: I added beforeSend property in my original code(not in jsfiddle) where I have jquery.validate.min.js added. It still does not make the ajax request work...

Comment: It's hard to tell why the AJAX request is not going through, unless you inspect it.

I took the trouble of creating another fiddle to explain why things are not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pkcgh/

If you look at the code, the code block within .validate method never gets executed because whatever that .validate method is trying to do, it's not working. 

Unfortunately, I don't know much about jQuery validate plugin to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I just made some changes and retained the submitHandler line as it is and finally it worked only cos of beforeSend(). I still wonder why the ajax request was not processed when the `$("#addsitecode_submit").html(ajax_load);` was placed outside the $.ajax(). But thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad things worked out for you. Thanks for choosing my reply as the answer.